# How to configure Vite so that plugins can run correctly outside the root directory?

Tags: javascript, webpack, rollup, vite, esbuild

### Background

I want to start vite service in any directory to support `test file` preview。And:

- the test file will be resolved by `testFilePlugin`
- the `testFilePlugin` contains some code that depends on commonJS
  modules: `import { Fragment } from 'react/jsx-runtime'`
- the `react` has been installed in my project

### Failed 1

```
// main.js
import { createServer } from 'vite';
import testFilePlugin from 'testFilePlugin';

createServer({
  root: __dirname, // my project root
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@root': process.cwd(),
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    testFilePlugin(), // handle for testFile
  ],
});
```

Then, I import other project modules in this way：

```
import testFile from '@root/xx.test'
```

Then, I just execute `main.js` in other directory. **But got an error:**

`[vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "react/jsx-runtime" from "xx.test". Does the file exist?`

I confirmed that `react` has been installed in my project directory. so this error may be because vite is looking for modules based on other directories's node_modules。

So I thought of using [@rollup/plugin-node-resolve](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/node-resolve) to manually add [moduleDirectories](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/node-resolve#moduledirectories):

### Failed 2

```
// main.js
import { createServer } from 'vite';
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import testFilePlugin from 'testFilePlugin';

createServer({
  root: __dirname, // my project root
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@root': process.cwd(),
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    nodeResolve({
      moduleDirectories: module.paths, // add my project moduleDirectories
    }),
    testFilePlugin(), // handle for testFile
  ],
});
```

No more compilation errors after retrying! But a runtime error occurred in the browser：

`Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/@fs/.../myProject/node_modules/react/jsx-runtime' does not provide an export named 'Fragment`

So I thought that I should use the [@rollup/plugin-commonjs](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs) plugin to solve this problem：

### Failed 3

```
// main.js
import { createServer } from 'vite';
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import testFilePlugin from 'testFilePlugin';

createServer({
  root: __dirname, // my project root
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@root': process.cwd(),
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    nodeResolve({
      moduleDirectories: module.paths, // add my project moduleDirectories
    }),
    commonjs({
      include: /node_modules/,
    }),
    testFilePlugin(), // handle for testFile
  ],
});
```

No runtime errors this time at last! But the page is always loading.

Looking at the network requests, I found 4 **pending requests**:

- `http://localhost:3000/@id/__x00__/.../myProject/node_modules/react/cjs/react-jsx-runtime.production.min.js?commonjs-proxy`
- `http://localhost:3000/@id/__x00__/.../myProject/node_modules/react/cjs/react-jsx-runtime.development.js?commonjs-proxy`
- `http://localhost:3000/@id/__x00__/.../myProject/node_modules/react/cjs/react-jsx-runtime.development.js?commonjs-proxy`
- `http://localhost:3000/@id/__x00__/.../myProject/node_modules/object-assign/index.js?v=a502bc89?commonjs-proxy`
- `http://localhost:3000/@id/__x00__/.../myProject/node_modules/.vite/react.js?v=a502bc89&es-interop?commonjs-proxy`

After the above failed attempts, I decided to give up on the Vite plugin to solve this problem！

Then, let me share some successful solutions that I have tried：

### Success 1

Also install react in the target directory.

### Success 2

Manually add `react/jsx-runtime` to vite's [pre-bundling](https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling.html):

```
{
...
    optimizeDeps: {
      include: ['react/jsx-runtime']
    },
...
}
```

### Success 3

Import then test file **in other directories** through the test file **in my project**:

```
// index.js in my project
import testFile from './xx.test'
```

---

```
// xx.test in my project
import testFile from '@root/xx.test' // import other directory test file
```

### End

1. I wonder if there is a better solution for this requirement?
2. What is the reason for the failure of `Failed x`?

Comment: Where are located the `*.test` file ? Are they in a specific folder, or in a **relative** folder ?

Comment: specific folder. imported from '@root/*.test'. And the @root may be any folder

Comment: if you can, please share a reproducible project as I miss a bit time, and meanwhile you can change the alias to:  `'@root': path.resolve(__dirname, './folder_with_test')`  (you will need to `import path from 'path'`)

Comment: the @root alias is actually an unnecessary information for my question. My Project is a command-line tool, so any directory may be `@root`

Comment: I can't understand your comment... and now, also can't understand your question. be more specific or provide a reproducible project.